# Creating drive clone from ghost 15 boot disc

Tags: hard-drive, ghost

I only have my phone as an internet connection right now so I am finding it hard to Google an answer.

Is it possible to use the ghost boot disk (standard disk that comes with purchase) to create a clone of the main drive to a new one?  I don't see that option from the boot disc I only see backup and restore pretty much.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to back-up your disk to a third device (i.e. a USB HDD) and then restore the image to your replacement disk.